# Максимальное количество символов в атрибуте alt у <img>?

Tags: html, css

Какое максимальное количество символов можно добавить в атрибут alt у метки ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В HTML 4 стоит ограничение в 64Кб: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/sgmldecl.html . В HTML 5, похоже, то же самое.